# Android, Use a Wrapper to execute a function or not

Tags: android, annotations, wrapper

I have the following situation I want to solve. I wrote my own small drawing engine based on a Canvas. I created for every renderable a base class, for example, line, text, point, etc. From these base classes, I created a few derived entity classes. I also implemented a layer management system which is based on an observer-pattern to toggle the visibility of the derived entity classes. So far so good.

Every derived entity class has its own onDraw function where something is drawn on the canvas e.g

```
@Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if(isVisible) {
            if (p1X != 0 && p1Y != 0 && p2X != 0 && p2Y != 0) {
                canvas.drawLine(
                        p1X,
                        p1Y,
                        p2X,
                        p2Y,
                        paint
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

The crucial part I want to improve is

```
if(isVisible){
   ...
}
```

I really want to do something like this

```
@isVisible
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   ...
}
```

If I would do this in Python, I would write a Decorator to wrap the onDraw function. 
But well, I want to write in Java and I'm a little bit clueless about how to do it. Maybe with an annotation (as I have shown it above as an idea), or are there other ways to do it?